How do I alter a table by using AFTER in hook update?
I am trying to alter an existing table to add new column. I am able to add new column successfully. But the created new column is added at the end of the table. I want the column to be added after a specific column.
Basically I would like to know the Drupal equivalent of
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD newcol varchar(1024) AFTER oldcol;

My Drupal update hook definition is as below.
  /**
  * Implements hook_update_N().
  */
  function my_module_update_8201() {
    $spec = array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'description' => "New Col",
      'length' => 1024,
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ); 
    $schema = Database::getConnection()->schema();
    $schema->addField('my_table', 'newcol', $spec);
    return $schema;
  }

I am able to achieve it with the below code using query method, but I looking for a way to implement it using addField Method.
Database::getConnection()->query('ALTER TABLE {' . $table . '} ADD COLUMN . [' . $field . '] VARCHAR(1024) AFTER oldcol');


This isn't supported by the MySQL driver included with core (Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Schema).
You'll either need to keep using the custom query method you mentioned, or create your own custom database driver (you can extend from the MySQL one). This driver would use its own custom Schema, to which you can add/edit a method which alters the table with the option of an AFTER keyword.

Thanks for the information.
